# Intercept navigation in webkit-sharp

Tags: webkit

I'm investigating whether I can use [webkit-sharp](http://www.ohloh.net/p/webkit-sharp) for my application.

The main thing I need is the ability to handle custom URIs: I want to **intercept link clicks and handle them myself**, e.g. by calling `WebView.LoadHtmlString`. I suspect this can be done with the `WebView.NavigationRequested` event, but I don't immediately see a way to suppress the normal URI handling. I also can't find any reference documentation for webkit-sharp or webkit itself.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently to suppress the normal URI handling, you have to set `NavigationRequestedEventArgs.RetVal` of the event arguments object to `1`, which is the value of `WEBKIT_NAVIGATION_RESPONSE_IGNORE` in the webkit header files.

Comment: This answers how to stop the request but not how to handle it.

Comment: @Sjoerd2228888: you can put whatever code you like in the NavigationRequested event handler. The main issue was just that the default handling would also still happen, and this answer explains how to stop that.

Comment: I expected that handling the response yourself means giving a custom answer to the request. That's what I am looking for and I do not know what code would do it.

Comment: As I said in the question, you can call WebView.LoadHtmlString to handle the event.

Comment: I hoped there was a way to create a HTTP response. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Wim! Please check [my question about WebKit-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576038/html-ui-using-webkit). I'm sure you can suggest something. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I know that in the Objective-C interface to WebKit you can use this WebPolicyDelegate method:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
```

And if you want to handle the navigation yourself you use:

```
[listener ignore];
```

And if you want the default behavior you use:

```
[listener use];
```

Which you pretty much found out for your webkit-sharp implementation as I was typing this.